# How to understand compiled Elixir Erlang function names

Tags: elixir

In ExProf, Elixir function names are printed out as what I assume is their Erlang names, after compilation. One example is

```
Enum.reduce/3
```

which is printed as

```
'Elixir.Enum':'-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-'/3
```

How do I parse this string? Where does the `-lists^foldl/2-0-` part come from? Why are there multiple `/3`? Why are some names `-` prefixed? What does the `^` mean? Why the `2-0-`?

Comment: Having a look at the [source](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/ad3c7c6c600e264c3cb00bba43b20b46c7e0e063/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L1683) it gets clear where the lists^foldl comes from. For the rest I am clueless, especially for the /2 part. It would be nice to know if the function name changes with each case in the source.

Comment: Some details: That's what the function reference looks like to erlang. The parts are in quotes because they contain characters that must be quoted in erlang atoms. The first part, before the `:` is the erlang module name that is generated, the second part is the function name that is generated. It's name is just a signature built out of the original elixir function name and where it delegates to. And then finally is the actual arity of the whole thing. why foldl is inserted into the signature with an arity of 2-0 is beyond me though.

Comment: Still it would be nice to know why this is done like that. If you have a look at the README at [ExProf](https://github.com/parroty/exprof) this naming scheme is not obvious at all. Anyway, ExProf doesn't seem to care about naming conventions and just takes the names from eprof (which is Erlang) as given.

Comment: Just realized `'Elixir.Enum':reduce/3` is also in the list of functions called.

Comment: @FilipHaglund For me this happens if I use maps as input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I parse this string?

`'Elixir.Enum':'-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-'/3` is the function reference syntax in Erlang referring to a function named `-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-` in the module `Elixir.Enum`, with arity 3, similar to `&Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3` in Elixir.

> Where does the `-lists^foldl/2-0-` part come from?

The `-$fn/$arity-$something-$count-` is the name returned by Erlang in stacktraces (and apparently profiling output) for an anonymous function defined inside `$fn/$arity`. Normally, you would see something like `-main/0-fun-0-`, i.e. `$something == "fun"`, for example, this:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def main do
    try do
      (fn -> raise("foo") end).()
    rescue
      _ -> IO.inspect System.stacktrace
    end
  end
end
```

prints:

```
[{Foo, :"-main/0-fun-0-", 0, [file: 'foo.ex', line: 4]},
 {Foo, :main, 0, [file: 'foo.ex', line: 4]},
 {:erl_eval, :do_apply, 6, [file: 'erl_eval.erl', line: 670]},
 {:elixir, :erl_eval, 3, [file: 'src/elixir.erl', line: 223]},
 {:elixir, :eval_forms, 4, [file: 'src/elixir.erl', line: 211]},
 {Code, :eval_string, 3, [file: 'lib/code.ex', line: 168]},
 {Kernel.CLI, :wrapper, 1, [file: 'lib/kernel/cli.ex', line: 437]},
 {Enum, :"-map/2-lists^map/1-0-", 2, [file: 'lib/enum.ex', line: 1184]}]
```

It's just that you're less likely to see `-fun-` ones in Elixir's default error messages because they're [normalized](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4f8adcbb1437c72ea43bb5172fc99810693977f3/lib/elixir/lib/exception.ex#L438-L443), to `anonymous fn/0 in Foo.main/0` in this case (this is why I printed the stacktrace above by calling `System.stacktrace/0` explicitly).

So where does `lists^foldl/2` come from? That's [generated by `sys_core_fold_lists`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/b834a527c2f420a80806fbf36d4585c1e530061c/lib/compiler/src/sys_core_fold_lists.erl#L209-L210), a module [called by `sys_core_fold`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/b834a527c2f420a80806fbf36d4585c1e530061c/lib/compiler/src/sys_core_fold.erl#L730-L742) for modules defining `inline_list_funcs` compile attribute (the `Enum` module in Elixir [does do that](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4f8adcbb1437c72ea43bb5172fc99810693977f3/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L179)), which "Inlines high order lists functions from the lists module". This inlining also gives the name "lists^foldl/2" to the anonymous function instead of just being "fun".

Here's a simple demo:

```
defmodule Fold do
  @compile :inline_list_funcs

  def main do
    sum([1, 2, 3])
  end

  def sum(list) do
    :lists.foldl(fn a, b -> raise "foo" end, 0, list)
  end
end

Fold.main
```

With `@compile :inline_list_funcs`, the output is:

```
** (RuntimeError) foo
    fold.exs:9: anonymous fn/2 in Fold.sum/1
    fold.exs:9: Fold."-sum/1-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

and without it, the output is:

```
** (RuntimeError) foo
    fold.exs:9: anonymous fn/2 in Fold.sum/1
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1263: :lists.foldl/3
    (elixir) lib/code.ex:363: Code.require_file/2
```

With that attribute, we don't have any stacktrace entry for the `lists` module, even though we're explicitly calling `:lists:foldl`.

> Why are there multiple `/3`?

That seems to be a side effect of Erlang including the arity of the current function when naming an anonymous function.

> Why are some names `-` prefixed?

Explained above.

> What does the `^` mean?

It's just a name that [`sys_core_fold_lists:call/4`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/b834a527c2f420a80806fbf36d4585c1e530061c/lib/compiler/src/sys_core_fold_lists.erl#L210) chose.

> Why the `2-0-`?

`2` comes from [`sys_core_fold_lists:call/4`](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/b834a527c2f420a80806fbf36d4585c1e530061c/lib/compiler/src/sys_core_fold_lists.erl#L209-L210). `0` is [referred to as "count" in `Exception.format_mfa/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/4f8adcbb1437c72ea43bb5172fc99810693977f3/lib/elixir/lib/exception.ex#L427) but I'm not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0):

It is a generated name for some 'anonymous' function inside `Enum.reduce` implementation. I assume this function is defined inline and passed as an argument to the `lists:foldl`, hence the name. AFAIK such names are generated not by Elixir but by Erlang itself.